# Add debug symbols for .NET 3.5 Debugging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a Unity application and a C# DLL, created by Visual Studio 2013, that I want to debug. I do this by going to `DEBUG > Attach to Process` inside Visual Studio 2013, and if I choose Native code, I can set breakpoints for C++ code and etc. However, when I choose the option for .NET 3.5, it says that the breakpoint will never be reached as the symbols have not been loaded.

How do I load debug symbols for .NET 3.5 for Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Can't you also attach the debugger to that process using a more recent version of Visual Studio (2017 or 2015)?

Comment: Sure can, but I don't think that would fix the problem, would it?

Comment: Let me take a step back. Is it symbols for .net 3.5 you are having issues with or the symbols of your application? I am thinking it is the latter, that you can't hit the break point because the symbol can't be loaded for the application *which happens to be compiled using the target framework 3.5*.

Comment: If that is the case then it's a matter of figuring out why the symbol file (corresponding .pdb file) is not being loaded. It could be because it can't be found, it is not being generated, you are running a build that does not have a generated .pdb, you are running in release mode, or that the built `.pdb` file does not match the built `.dll` (the 2 must be a set compiled at the same time, they are not swapable).

Comment: Is the DLL you want to debug build using `debug` configuration? If it is build using `release` the .pdb file may not have the necessary information for debugging, or not build at all.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the below MSDN links

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2017
```

You can load the symbols from pdf file and making configurations in pdb file you can manage the symbols while debugging the application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

The answer is simple, you have a dll, debug symbols are .pdb files. You need to open and build c# solution (class library) in visual studio and look in the output directory of the project, usualy bin->debug. Get the pdb and store them somewhere. Then when you run your unity applicatio, you use visual studio (can be any version of visual doesnt matter), attach to process, but make sure the pdb's you saved have been loaded into visual studio by following the microsoft documentation above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the library's symbols file, you can decompile the library with the free decompiler [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and attach Visual Studio to the [dotPeek's symbols server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html?Wave=8).

Then disable `Enable Just My Code` in Visual Studio's debugging option. Remember to enable it again, when you're done, because it hurts the performance.